# yellow dotted wireframe appears when I mistakenly press Shift-t instead of Ctrl-t

Tags: mesh

When I attempt to triangulate a mesh I end up with that dotted yellow bounding box when I mistakenly press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.  I cannot get rid of it by using *Undo*.

From what I can tell, it has something to do with Texture Space but I cannot find anything in the Object Data panel that will remove it once it's there.

So does anyone know how to get rid of this and set things back to how they were before I hit that wrong shortcut?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find you are accidentally hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> too often, you can disable the shortcut.

Go to *File* > *User Preferences* > *Input* tab. Unfortunately, searching "texture" for name will not find anything, so instead search for "Shift T", changing the Filter Type to "Key-Binding".

[image]

Scroll down the results returned to the **3D View** set of shortcuts, and expand the **Translate** arrow. Uncheck the **Edit Texture Space** checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Cant search writing Shift T in the search box, using blender 2.76b

Answer (score 34):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does indeed turn on the 'Texture Space' display mode.

To disable it go to *Object*> *Display*> *Texture Space* and untick the checkbox:

[image]

Comment: Note that it also translates the texture space, so you might want to make sure it's reset to `0,0,0` in *Properties > Object data > Texture space > Location*.