# What does this dotted box mean in the viewport?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

A while ago, I realized there was a dotted box at the origin of my chair object. I don't remember when it appeared. It moves whenever I re-position the origin, and it only appears in the layer my object is in. What does this box represent? Is there a way to turn it on and off for any object? It hasn't caused any problems for me, I'm just interested in what it is.[image]

Comment: After reading Refracktor's answer, I looked up texture space, and I found that there was already a question asked about [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13417/yellow-dotted-wireframe-appears-when-i-mistakenly-press-shift-t-instead-of-ctrl).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have pressed Shift+T, or enabled *Texture Space* in the Object tab of the Properties panel.

[image: Texture Space]

The size and location of the Texture Space are found here, in the Object Data tab:

[image]