# Bounding box like object stuck in viewport

Tags: 3d-view

I've used Blender for 4 years, off and on, yet I've never come across this before. I've attached two images to try and make it clear. It looks like a bounding box, it's not an object I've added and I cannot find anyway to get rid of it. Wasn't there last night.

Can anyone tell me the "Kick myself" short cut to get rid of it please? As I've not the foggiest.

Thank you!
[image: Material Mode]

[[image: Wireframe Object Mode]

Comment: See Properties editor > Object tab > Display rollout if there aren't any options activated like Texture Space or Bounding Box, maybe related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13417/yellow-dotted-wireframe-appears-when-i-mistakenly-press-shift-t-instead-of-ctrl and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3366/display-bounding-box-around-objects

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mr Zak's links, the answer-for anyone else stuck, unable to find a good Google phrase to find it-is in the Object->Display menu.

You get it by hitting Shift-T by accident!

[image]

Comment: Just to flesh this out.. Shit-T displays the [Texture Space](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv_image/uv/generated_uvs.html#editing) of the object, which can be scaled or translated .. you don't seem to be able to rotate it? I can't see why not...